# How to deserialize MessagePack in Spring Cloud Stream App

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I'm trying to create a Kafka streams app using Spring Cloud Stream, but am struggling to deserialize the input messages, whose values have been encoded using [MessagePack](https://msgpack.org/index.html).

Here's what I've got so far:

```
// TransactionApplication.java

@SpringBootApplication
public class TransactionApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(TransactionApplication.class, args);
  }

  public static class TransactionConsumer {

    @Bean
    public Serde<Transaction> transactionSerde() {
      ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new MessagePackFactory());
      return new JsonSerde<Transaction>(mapper);
    }

    @Bean
    public Consumer<KStream<String, Transaction>> process() {
      return input -> input.foreach((key, value) -> {
        System.out.println("Key: " + key + " Value: " + value);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

```
// Transaction.java

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Transaction {
  String item;
  Number amount;
}
```

I'm getting the error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No type information in headers and no default type provided.

My application.yml is:

```
spring.cloud.stream:
  bindings:
    process-in-0:
      destination: transactions
  kafka:
    streams:
      binder:
        applicationId: transactions-application
        configuration:
          commit.interval.ms: 100
```

After including `spring.json.value.default.type: com.example.Transaction` underneath the `configuration` node of my applicaton.yml, I'm getting another error. See below.

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Can't deserialize data [[123, 34, 105, 116, 101, 109, 34, 58, 32, 34, 112, 114, 105, 118, 97, 116, 101, 32, 106, 101, 116, 34, 44, 32, 34, 97, 109, 111, 117, 110, 116, 34, 58, 32, 53, 48, 50, 125]] from topic [transactions]
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `com.jackdry.processors.json.Transaction` (although at least one Creator exists): no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (123)
 at [Source: (byte[])"{"item": "private jet", "amount": 502}"; line: -1, column: 0]
```

Comment: Is `applicaton.yml` a misspelling here, or is it wrongly named in your system too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide a hint to the deserializer to tell it what object to create from the encoded payload.

If the record was created by the Spring JsonSerializer, the hints are in the headers.

If not, you have to provide the hint in the streams configuration.

You need to show your `application.yml/properties`.

Comment: Thanks Gary, I've added my application.yml. Might you be able to tell me what exactly I should add? Sorry, I'm very new to Java, let alone Spring.

Comment: Underneath the binder `configuration:` node, add `spring.json.value.default.type=com.foo.Transaction`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gary. Unfortunately I'm now getting a different error, which I've added to my original post. I'd be so grateful if you could quickly take a look at it.

Comment: `no int/Int-argument constructor` I am not familiar with MessagePack; normally, Jackson needs a `no-arg` constructor `Foo()` to create a `Foo`.  But it appears in this case it's looking for a constructor (`Transaction(int someInteger)`) and there isn't one. I'm done for the day but if you can add your `Transaction` class to the question I can take a look tomorrow.

Comment: My transaction class is in the second code block. Okay, thanks a lot. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Ah - the dreaded lombok - but I see you have a no-args CTOR created by it - I have no idea why it's looking for CTOR requiring an `int` - especially given that it has no int fields; although it does have a number - perhaps this is some artifact of MessagePack. It wouldn't hurt adding `public Transaction(int dummy) { }` to see what happens.

Comment: Since you are explicitly instantiating the `Serde` object in your @Bean method, you can use the constructor  `new JsonSerde<>(Transaction.class, mapper)` and thus avoid that property Gary mentioned above (the default.type). However, as Gary said, I think your latest errors are due to the message pack library you are using.

Comment: Ah I found the error. In my python program which was publishing to the `transactions` topic, I was sending `msgpack.packb(json.dumps({"item": "private jet", amount: 240}))` instead of just `msgpack.packb({"item": "private jet", amount: 240})`. Thank you both for your help, and also for your brilliant work on Spring Cloud Stream. I'm really enjoying using it so far, and have learnt lots from your GitHub examples.